# In test cases(unit-testing), Django pre_save signal can not be caught

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, django-signals

In Django, my code on catching pre_save signal works well. However, in testcases in tests.py, the signal handler cannot receive anything. Is there any hint for this problem?

- It seems that my testcases and signal handler are in different apps. Is this the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that my testcases and signal handler are in different apps. Is this the cause of the problem?

Yes. Each app's `tests.py` is atomic. `import` your signal registration code or connect them manually somewhere in your test to make sure they are listening:

> *You can put signal handling and
>   registration code anywhere you like.
>   However, you'll need to make sure that
>   the module it's in gets imported early
>   on so that the signal handling gets
>   registered before any signals need to
>   be sent.*

(From: *[Listening to signals, Connecting receiver functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions)*.)